# puppet "Connection refused"

Tags: rhel-5, puppet

My puppet agent is getting `Connection refused` when it tries to connect to the master. However, other interactions work, and the first page of Google hits aren't helping. What am I missing?

I can successfully send a certificate request, and it is successfully signed and returned. So, I know *some* communication is getting through. But, the `--server` argument is required.

```
[testuser@agent puppet]$ sudo puppet certificate generate agent.dev.example.com --ca-location remote --debug --server master.net.example.com
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file rolemod does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Failed to load library 'selinux' for feature 'selinux'
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/facts]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/agent.dev.example.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys/agent.dev.example.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: Finishing transaction 23570689626320
info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for agent.dev.example.com
info: Certificate Request fingerprint (md5): [REDACTED]
true

[testuser@agent puppet]$ sudo puppet certificate find --ca-location remote --server master.net.example.com agent.dev.example.com
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[REDACTED]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

[testuser@agent puppet]$ sudo ls -la /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 pe-puppet pe-puppet 2017 Apr  8 10:17 /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 pe-puppet pe-puppet 1984 Apr  8 10:29 /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/agent.dev.example.com.pem
```

However, no combination of switches avoids a `Connection refused` message when the agent tries to connect. It errors every time. Here's the long `--debug` output. I've added line breaks for readability.

```
[ testuser@agent ] $ sudo puppet agent -d --no-daemonize --test --detailed-exitcodes
debug: Failed to load library 'selinux' for feature 'selinux'
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roleadd does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist

debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/classes.txt]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/run/pe-puppet/agent.pid]: Autorequiring File[/var/run/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/client_data]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/clientbucket]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state/resources.txt]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state/state.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state/graphs]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/agent.dev.example.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/client_yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/facts]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/agent.dev.example.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys/agent.dev.example.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: Finishing transaction 23551325708480

debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/facts]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/agent.dev.example.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys/agent.dev.example.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/opt/lib/pe-puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/agent.dev.example.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
debug: Finishing transaction 23551324209860

debug: Using cached certificate for ca
debug: Using cached certificate for agent.dev.example.com
debug: Finishing transaction 23551323810000
debug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds

info: Retrieving plugin
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: Using cached certificate for ca
debug: Using cached certificate for agent.dev.example.com
debug: Using cached certificate_revocation_list for ca
debug: Finishing transaction 23551323523420

info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_cachememfree.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_date.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_u01disk.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_tmpdisk.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_rootdisk.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_oradumpdisk.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_cpufreqs.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_uptime.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/mounts.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_vardisk.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_cputempaverage.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_cpufreq.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_appsdisk.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_u60disk.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_cpumaxfreq.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_bootdisk.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_cpucores.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_custom_build.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_cpufreqout.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_issue.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_cputemp.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_cpuaverage.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/bpa_cputime.rb

debug: catalog supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml dot pson raw yaml; using pson
info: Caching catalog for agent.dev.example.com
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderOpenrc: file /sbin/rc-service does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderGentoo: file /sbin/rc-update does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderLaunchd: file /bin/launchctl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderSystemd: file /bin/systemctl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderDebian: file /usr/sbin/update-rc.d does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderRunit: file /usr/bin/sv does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderDaemontools: file /usr/bin/svc does not exist
debug: Creating default schedules
debug: Finishing transaction 23551322650180

debug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
info: Applying configuration version '1365443005'

debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/util]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_accounts/Anchor[pe_accounts::begin]/before: requires Class[Pe_accounts::Groups]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/util/actionpolicy.rb]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/server.cfg]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/puppetral.rb]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/application/puppetd.rb]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/application/package.rb]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Metadata/File[/opt/puppet/sbin/refresh-mcollective-metadata]/before: requires Cron[pe-mcollective-metadata]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[mcollective-cert.pem]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/application/service.rb]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/puppetd.ddl]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_accounts::Groups/before: requires Anchor[pe_accounts::end]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/security/sshkey.rb]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/security]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[puppet-dashboard-public.pem]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/require: requires Anchor[pe_mcollective::begin]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/before: requires Anchor[pe_mcollective::end]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[mcollective-public.pem]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[mcollective-private.pem]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_compliance::Agent/require: requires Anchor[pe_compliance::begin]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_compliance::Agent/before: requires Anchor[pe_compliance::end]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/puppetral.ddl]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/package.ddl]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/require: requires Anchor[pe_mcollective::begin]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/before: requires Anchor[pe_mcollective::end]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl/clients/mcollective-public.pem]/require: requires File[mcollective-public.pem]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl/clients/mcollective-public.pem]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/registration]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[peadmin-public.pem]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/registration/meta.rb]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/puppetd.rb]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/service.rb]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Metadata/require: requires Anchor[pe_mcollective::begin]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Metadata/before: requires Anchor[pe_mcollective::end]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/security/aespe_security.rb]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/package.rb]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/service.ddl]/notify: subscribes to Service[mcollective]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/util/actionpolicy.rb]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/util]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[mcollective-cert.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/puppetral.rb]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/puppetd.ddl]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl/clients]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[puppet-dashboard-public.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl/clients]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/security/sshkey.rb]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/security]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/puppetral.ddl]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[mcollective-private.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[mcollective-public.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/package.ddl]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/puppetd.rb]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/registration/meta.rb]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/registration]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[peadmin-public.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl/clients]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Posix/File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl/clients/mcollective-public.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/ssl/clients]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/service.ddl]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/package.rb]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/security/aespe_security.rb]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/security]
debug: /Stage[main]/Pe_mcollective::Plugins/File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/service.rb]: Autorequiring File[/opt/puppet/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent]
debug: /Schedule[daily]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
debug: /Schedule[monthly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
debug: /Schedule[hourly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson

err: /Stage[main]/Sys-status/File[/usr/local/bin/sys-status.rb]: Could not evaluate: Connection refused - connect(2) Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet/modules/sys-status/sys-status.rb: Connection refused - connect(2) at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/sys-status/manifests/init.pp:24

debug: /Schedule[never]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
debug: Prefetching crontab resources for cron
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: /Schedule[weekly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
debug: /Schedule[puppet]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
debug: Service[mcollective](provider=redhat): Executing '/sbin/service pe-mcollective status'
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderRedhat: Executing '/sbin/chkconfig pe-mcollective'
debug: Finishing transaction 23551325678500
debug: Storing state
debug: Stored state in 0.07 seconds
notice: Finished catalog run in 2.53 seconds
debug: Value of 'preferred_serialization_format' (pson) is invalid for report, using default (b64_zlib_yaml)
debug: report supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml raw yaml; using b64_zlib_yaml
```

Adding a `--server master.net.example.com` does not change this output, and the file does exist on the server. Finally, my `puppet.conf` file does have the master server specified.

```
[ testuser@agent ] $ sudo cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
[main]
    vardir = /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet
    logdir = /var/log/pe-puppet
    rundir = /var/run/pe-puppet
    modulepath = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules:/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules
    user = pe-puppet
    group = pe-puppet
    archive_files = true
    #archive_file_server = puppet
    archive_file_server = master.net.example.com
    pluginsync = true

[agent]
    certname = agent.dev.example.com
    #server = puppet
    server = master.net.example.com
    report = true
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
    graph = true
    pluginsync = true
```

One final note: I am familiar with ssh port forwarding (`-L`). If someone can point me to the agent-side syntax to specify the master listening port, I can give that a try. That will rule out whether or not I'm being filtered somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the URL for the source of the file resource from puppet://puppet/modules/sys-status/sys-status.rb to puppet:///modules/sys-status/sys-status.rb.

It tries to get it from a puppet server named 'puppet', which it cannot connect to. Removing it will make it fetch the file from the master it's connecting to.

Ger

Comment: That's what I get for inheriting someone else's configuration. Fixed, and thank you!